# Being sure that mpi split work among cores

Tags: mpi, multicore

As you know mpi can run a bunch of processes even though there is only one processor with one core. Let's say I have a dual core single processor. If I run a program with `mpiexec.mpich -np 2 ./out` how can I be sure that the work was split among two cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way for you to confirm that you're running on both cores is to do something like a tight while loop that will spike the processor usage:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    while(1) {}
}
```

Then you can to look at your usage with something like `top` to make sure it's what you expect.

If you want to have fine-grained control over where your processes are run, MPICH has options to let you do that. You can find out all of the options on the [wiki](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager#Process-core_Binding) page. There's flags to let you bind to cores, hardware threads, sockets, etc.

Comment: what should I expect when I use top?

Comment: That you have multiple processes at 100ish%.